# Laravel model binding based on GET-parameter instead of URI-segment

Tags: laravel

I have route like

```
Route::match(['GET'], 'banana/{id}', 'BananaController@view');
Route::bind('id', function ($id): ?Banana
    {
        return Banana::findOrFail($id);
    });
```

So, I will have nice model binding in controller like

```
public function view(Banana $banana)
{
    return view('view', [
        'banana' => $banana,
    ]);
}
```

This will work on url

```
https://bananas.com/banana/666
```

But I need this action on url

```
https://bananas.com/banana?id=666
```

How can I make this model binding using GET-parameter instead of URI-segment?

Comment: Why you want it to make query bind instead of parameter?

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar I don't think it's relevant, but answer is, I'm rewriting some old API and need to keep URIs just same as they are now.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably adding a GET route and retrieving the query directly.

```
Route::get('/banana', function (Request $request) {
    $id = $request->query('id');
    $banana = Banana::findOrFail($id);
    return view('view', ['banana' => $banana]);
});
```

More information can be found below:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-input-from-the-query-string

Comment: This is not a model binding.